# scalar/array multiplication return Any type

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, mypy, typing

I wonder why mypy produces so many "Returning Any from function declared to return ..." errors when it has to deal with numpy. In the example below, `a` is an array and `b` is a scalar. As I see it, there is no way in which `np.exp(a*x)` would return anything else but another array. Even if `x` was `np.inf`, the result would still be an array. So why does mypy think the function could return any type?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

def func(a: NDArray[np.float64], x: float) -> NDArray[np.float64]:
    return np.exp(a*x)
```

PS: check the above code with `mypy --warn-return-any [file name]`, then you should see:

> a.py:5: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "ndarray[Any, dtype[floating[_64Bit]]]"  [no-any-return]

- python 3.10.8
- mypy 0.991
- numpy 1.24.0

Comment: Probably because `np.exp` itself isn't properly typed. If it claims to return `Any`, that's all `mypy` has to go on.

Comment: (If `np.exp` isn't hinted at all, which is more likely, then `mypy` assumes a return type of `Any`.)

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, too. But the return type of `np.exp(a)`, e.g., is indeed an array type.

Comment: Do you have NumPy type stubs installed? If I try to run `reveal_type(np.exp)` in `mypy`, I get back `Any` (after an error complaining about being unable to find a library stub for `bumpy`).

Comment: You don't have to install any type stubs; numpy now has build-in typing support.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what was up with previous test installation, but it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with `a*x`, not `np.exp` as I had originally guessed. If you introduce an explicitly hinted temporary variable, the problem goes away:

```
$ cat tmp.py
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

def func(a: NDArray[np.float64], x: float) -> NDArray[np.float64]:
    y: NDArray[np.float64] = a*x
    return np.exp(y)
$ mypy --warn-return-any tmp.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Why type inference fails, I'm not sure. Failure to hint `NDArray.__mul__`?